# Kali install no operating system issue

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux

I was wanting to get into Kali Linux but after installing it on my empty laptop it says there is no operating system after rebooting. I used a USB (used rufus) to install. Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. While trying to use the boot repair tool I found a folder in the UEFI boot order called EFI with GRUB in it. It now boots into Kali